# How to display a XML file in a folder like system

Tags: python, html, xml

I have searched quite a bit for some help on this but most information about XML and Python is about how to read and parse files, not how to write them. I currently have a script that outputs the file system of a folder as an XML file but I want this file to include HTML tags that can be read on the web.

Also, I am looking for a graphical folder style display of the XML information. I have seen this solved in javascript but I don't have any experience in javascript so is this possible in python?

```
import os
import sys
from xml.sax.saxutils import quoteattr as xml_quoteattr

dirname = sys.argv[1]
a = open("output2.xml", "w") 

def DirAsLessXML(path):
    result = '<dir name = %s>\n' % xml_quoteattr(os.path.basename(path))
    for item in os.listdir(path):
        itempath = os.path.join(path, item)
        if os.path.isdir(itempath):
            result += '\n'.join('  ' + line for line in 
                DirAsLessXML(os.path.join(path, item)).split('\n'))
        elif os.path.isfile(itempath):
            result += '  <file name=%s />\n' % xml_quoteattr(item)
    result += '</dir>'
    return result

if __name__ == '__main__':

    a.write('<structure>\n' + DirAsLessXML(dirname))
```

Comment: If it needs to work in a Web browser, you'll have to use JavaScript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally it's not a good idea to code HTML directly in Python by building strings as you do it. You won't understand what kind of HTML you produce if look at your code in a month or so. I recommend using a [templating](https://stackoverflow.com/q/98245/151299) [engine](http://wiki.python.org/moin/Templating).

Alternatively, as you are converting from XML to XML, [XSLT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XSLT) (an XML transformation language) seems like a good solution.

Concerning JavaScript, you'll need it if you want an *interactive* folder view. But this does not influence how to generate the HTML page. Whatever approach you use, just add a script include tag to the HTML header and implement the JavaScript part in an extra file (the one you include, of course).